# Automatically create alias in linux

Tags: linux, backup, alias, rsync

I need to create script which would be ran by cron each day. Purpose of that script would be to create alias for one directory that each day has different name.  The directory name changes it's name each day like 2013-11-11, 2013-12-11 etc. Actually, new directory get's created. 
I figured out that I can list that recent directory using

```
dirname=$(ls -lt --time=ctime | sed -n 3p | sed 's/^.* //' )
```

This gets the name of most recent created directory.
Now, the problem is how to make alias for that directory to something like "backup".  I  have rsync creating backup from another server so I need to have something that I can "call" for from that server.  I can't create cron for directory itself since it changes names each day. 
How can I create alias, each day, for most recently created directory ?

Comment: What do you mean by alias?  Can't you just delete/create a hard link every time?

Comment: Something like ln /disk/backup/test/  /disk/backup/$dirname  where dirname would be the name that I get using the above script. ? Would it be enough that I just run  cron with this kind of script each day and this link would get overwritten with new one or I need to delete existing one to create another one which points to directory with different name ?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to make your own poor man's [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system... I then strongly suggest to use a real one like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Almost ... if I understood your initial request correctly the invocation 
should be the other way round (the -f forces the link, saving you the need 
to delete the old link first):

```
ln -f /disk/backup/$dirname /disk/backup/test
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That is what I ought. btw, wouldn't it be better to use softlink for this and not hardlink ?  And if I'm getting this right now. I need to make a bash script which would 1. Check if softlink/hardlink exists and remove it. 2. Get path to new directory using the script from first post. 3. Create softlink/hardlink for that directory    After that, I can  use that link on another server to get  backup using rsync.

Comment: Hard-links shouldn't require any special smarts from rsync, soft-links might need extra command-line switches; I don't know for sure what rsyncs default behaviour with soft links is.